# PHP7 UTF-8 codepoint escape sequence with variable

Tags: php, variables, unicode, escaping, sequence

PHP 7 introduced [Unicode Codepoint Escape Syntax](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/unicode_escape) which is very easy to use, but I can't get it to work with a variable as a codepoint.

```
echo "\u{1f602}"; // echoes 

$em = "1f602";
echo sprintf("\u{%x}", $em); // returns error "Invalid UTF-8 codepoint escape sequence"
```

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: String escapes really just work as code literals, not in combination with interpolation.